# Verifying Full database backups "WITH CHECKSUM"

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, backup

We have a daily maintenance plan in SQL Server 2005 that performs a full backup to disk using the "Back Up Database Task".

"Verify backup integrity" is enabled but from what I understand data integrity is only validated if the backup media contains a checksum, which is enabled by the "WITH CHECKSUM" option during the backup. I can see from generated T-SQL that the maintenance plan task does not create this so, apart from manually hacking the command's code, how do we specify this in the task (if it is indeed possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation it appears it is not possible to configure a task to validate the data integrity "WITH CHECKSUM" through the drag-drop features of SQL Server Management Studio alone. This command will need to be added to the T-SQL of the task

Comment: If you check the box in the task and simple click "View T-SQL" it will show you all that it does is issue a RESTORE VERIFYONLY command against the lastest backup file it finds in the msdb..backupset table.